# Converting matlab-style indexing to numpy

Tags: matlab, numpy

I would like to convert (a more complicated form of) the follwing Matlab code

```
a=zeros(9,9);
a(3+(1:3),6+(1:3))=1;
```

to Numpy. I tried

```
from numpy import zeros, r_

a=zeros((9,9))
a[3+r_[0:3],6+r_[0:3]] = 1
```

But this only puts 3 1's in the matrix. How can I write the matlab code in a similar (short) form in Python?

Comment: In case you've not seen it yet: http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users. The section titled "Linear Algebra Equivalents" may be particularly helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be honest, I'd probably just do

```
>>> a = zeros((9,9))
>>> a[3:6, 6:9] = 1
```

or the non-hardcoded equivalent.  If you want the indexing to look more like Matlab's here, though, then you can use [ix_](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):

```
>>> a = zeros((9,9))
>>> a[ix_(3+r_[0:3], 6+r_[0:3])] = 1
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Thing is, the hardcoded numbers aren't hardcoded, I simplified the code to its core form for StackOverflow. And what exactly do you mean with "non-hardcoded equivalent"?

Comment: I mean replace "3" with "y" and "6" with "y+dy", etc.